# reading bools from one form to another c#

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio

I have five buttons on one form that when clicked enables a bool each to be true or false, they also load a new form. When that form is loaded I need the new form to check first which of those bools are true or false. This will then lead to the form loading the correct data.

I set the bools to public thinking that this would work, and in the form2_load i checked which   one is true. however this does not seem to work. I tried first by just changing  a label and it's text. The text doesn't changed and I don't think the bools are being read or checked.

Does anyone know what the problem could be?

Form1 code:

```
public bool Room1;
public bool Room2;
public bool Room3;
public bool Room4;
public bool Room5;

private void btnRoom1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        this.Hide();

        //This displays Form2
        Form2 RoomTemplate = new Form2();
        RoomTemplate.Show();

        Room1 = true;
        Room2 = false;
        Room3 = false;
        Room4 = false;
        Room5 = false;

    }
```

Form2 code:

```
public Form3()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        Form2 Rooms = new Form2();

        if (Rooms.Room1 == true)
        {
            lblTitle.Text = "Living Room";
        }

        if (Rooms.Room2 == true)
        {
            lblTitle.Text = "Dining Room";
        }
```

Comment: Whoa - first of all are you not missing some code? You say Form2 code: but you show the constructor for Form3 that initialises form2... from what I can see though, it looks ok but post the missing code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is one way to do it:

```
public bool Room1;
public bool Room2;
public bool Room3;
public bool Room4;
public bool Room5;
private void btnRoom1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    this.Hide();

    Room1 = true;
    Room2 = false;
    Room3 = false;
    Room4 = false;
    Room5 = false;

    //This displays Form2
    Form2 RoomTemplate = new Form2(this);
    RoomTemplate.Show();
}

public class Form2()
{
    public Form2(Form1 form1)
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        if(form1.Room1 == true)
        {
            lblTitle.Text="Living Room";
        }
        else if(form1.Room2==true)
        {
            //
        }
        //
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Don't create a new instance of `Form2` in `Form3`. If you don't want to pass references around or do singleton then just assign a reference to `Form2` in its constructor to a static property. Something like:

```
public static Form2 Instance { get; set; }
public Form2() {
    Instance = this;
}
```

Then in `Form3` access the booleans with `Form2.Instance.Room1`.

Answer (score 2):

> Form2 Rooms = new Form2();

In constructor of Form3 you are creating new object of Form2 and it will have all bool properties with default values as this is not the calling object it is new instance of Form2. You should pass Form2 object in constructor of Form2 and access the public properties there.

**In Form2**

```
Form3 RoomTemplate = new Form3(this);
RoomTemplate.Show();
```

**In Form2**

Constrtuctor of Form3

```
public Form3(Form frm)
{
     MessageBox.Show(frm.Room1.ToString());    
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In `Form3`, you need the instance of `Form2` you're modifying somewhere else.  Your `Form3` will only ever use what `Form2` sets as the defaults for those booleans because you're instantiating a new `Form2` which will have no knowledge of what you previously set.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are setting the values on the `btnRoom1_Click` event but you are referencing the `Room` values directly after the for is instantiated. I.e. before the `btnRoom1_Click` method is ever called.

Answer (score 0):

Form2 inside Form3 is not the same object as the form where the button is pressed. You could pass the Form2 object to Form3 (supposing that form2 opens Form3) or notify Form3 object when something happens inside Form2 or use a singleton Fomr2 or static fields